# Jquery datatable tabletool Save as Excel, CSV, PDF, copy and print not working when deployed on IIS7.5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, flash, iis-7.5, datatables

I have implemented the Save as Excel, CSV, copy and print tools in my website, and it is working perfectly when I run the website locally. When I deployed the website on IIS7.5 the buttons do not work at all. I've noticed that when I hover over the buttons and right click the flash information does not show up. What could be this problem? Could it be a security issue?

Comment: Are all paths to jquery libraries correct?

Comment: yes everything is working fine even on localhost. The buttons which cater the different exports does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds very much like you are using a relative path for the `.swf` file that becomes broken when you deploy to the server :

```
...
oTableTools: {
   sSwfPath: "/path-to-datatables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
   ...
}
...
```

use an absolute path instead :

```
...
oTableTools: {
   sSwfPath: "http://example.com/path-to-datatables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
   ...
}
...
```